# How to remove the header in SlickGrid?

Tags: html, css, slickgrid

I know that there is no API to remove the header row, but I'm sure it can be done by modifying some CSS. Any ideas ?

For example, here: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

**CSS experts !**
I need your help with this one.
I'm interested in changing the CSS code of the package that removes the header row. CSS code that can be loaded on top of the package is preferred.
The source code is here: http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid
(Press "Download Source")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that doing this is not supported in SlickGrid, at least at the moment.
The CSS workaround doesn't work because SlickGrid uses the DOM elements in the header to calculate the dimensions of the viewport.  Setting it to `display:none` makes SlickGrid think that the grid is 0 pixels wide.

You can sort of get around it by doing `$(".slick-header-columns").css("height","0px")` followed by a call to `grid.resizeCanvas()` to get rid of the remaining whitespace at the bottom of the grid.

Comment: Thanks ! The workaround works :) It would be nice to have this basic(?) feature in the future. Thank you for your time !

Comment: @moroshko: You can always add it to Issues on GitHub as a feature request ;)

Comment: You can, at least with 2.0, set css styles and the grid will handle it without explicitly needing to do it via javascript and calling grid.resizeCanvas() as it is calculated correctly on the first render.
.slick-header-columns{
 height: 0px;
}

.slick-header.ui-state-default{
 border: none;
}

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following to the grid options:

```
headerHeight: 0
```

and then in your css put something like:

```
#myGridID .slick-header-columns {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and simply not displaying does work:

```
$(element).find('.slick-header').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: This is a great answer, as it doesn't modify all the SlickGrid elements, but instead only the ones found in a container!

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work:

```
.slick-header-columns { display: none; }
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work. The rest of the cells disappear as well.

Comment: @Misha Moroshko: When I tried it using Firebug on the example page it worked just fine. I can't see anything in the HTML that would make the other cells disappear.

Comment: Could you please tell me where did you add this code using Firebug ?

Comment: I selected the `div` with class `slick-header-columns` and chose "Add property" to the class CSS rule.

Comment: It's strange. It really works with Firebug, but if I download the SlickGrid package and change this example as you proposed it does not work....

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to add one line to the slick.grid.js

function createColumnHeaders() {
**return;**
}

if you add a return to the first line inside of createColumnHeaders it seems to remove the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but works for me

```
$('#myGrid').find('.slick-header-column.ui-state-default').css('display', 'none');
```